# Direct link to create a Facebook event?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

Is there a direct link to bookmark that creates a new Facebook event?

The following button is associated with the URL `https://www.facebook.com/events/upcoming#` and thus does not directly link to creating a new event.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a direct link to a standalone page to create a new Facebook event.

That "Create" button is only designed to create that overlay you would have seen, and never take you to a page where you would fill in the event details.